# Thrift and Python: No module named 'six' for python

Tags: python-2.7, thrift

I'm attempting to compile and install Thrift but it's having issues finding modules within Python 2.7.11. Several others have posted about this issue but their issues contain slightly different scenarios than mine. When I run my Thrift "make check" I receive the following:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  check-local
/usr/local/bin/python3 setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
/usr/local/bin/python3 test/thrift_json.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test/thrift_json.py", line 24, in <module>
    from thrift.protocol.TJSONProtocol import TJSONProtocol
  File "/Users/mateo/Documents/Programming/Thrift.nosync/thrift-0.11.0/lib/py/build/lib.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.6/thrift/protocol/TJSONProtocol.py", line 20, in <module>
    from .TProtocol import (TType, TProtocolBase, TProtocolException,
  File "/Users/mateo/Documents/Programming/Thrift.nosync/thrift-0.11.0/lib/py/build/lib.macosx-10.12-x86_64-3.6/thrift/protocol/TProtocol.py", line 24, in <module>
    import six
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'six'
make[3]: *** [py3-test] Error 1
make[2]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
```

Some information on my system:

```
Mateos-MBP:test mateo$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
 echo $PATH
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

Within the Versions folder I only have '2.7' and 'Current' folders so I don't think I'm running into multiple versions stepping on themselves.

Finally, I am able to run a simple script like this and python doesn't error out at all:

```
import six
import sys

x=1
if x=1:
    print("Python is running and X is equal to 1")
else:
    print("Python is running and X is not equal to 1")
```

How do I get my Thrift install to recognize that the six module is installed?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have        import six in your code? if you don't then add it to the top
also  in your example of it working it does not run it!

Comment: In my code no. I haven't gotten that far yet but good thought. The Thrift compiler includes 'six' on line 24 of 'thrift/protocol/TProtocol.py'. Which I think is where the problem stems from.

Answer (score 0):

You might assume that everything you're doing is in python2.7 but it says:
"/usr/local/bin/python3 test/thrift_json.py" so the test is running python3. You need to have python3-six installed along with python2-six.